# ERROR_WEB_USER_INTERACTION_FAILURE when authenticating a user through Twitter (Firebase - Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, twitter, error-handling

Im getting an error whenever trying to authenticate a user through Twitter (Firebase). My code was working perfectly fine up until today. Nothing has changed but now Im receiving this error message:

```
Error creating user account:  Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17063 "The app verification process has failed, print and inspect the error details for more information" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_WEB_USER_INTERACTION_FAILURE, NSLocalizedFailureReason=[auth/invalid-credential] - Malformed response cannot be parsed from twitter.com for OAUTH1_REQUEST_TOKEN, NSLocalizedDescription=The app verification process has failed, print and inspect the error details for more information})
```

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same problem for 1 hour .. This is very problematic and blocks user authentication ..

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried looking this up but I've only found un-answered questions @RudyPley

Comment: A few people say to log out of the twitter account but it didn't work for me .. I will continue to search tonight, if I have a solution I will keep you posted! @Vandale

Comment: `print and inspect the error details for more information` is there any additional information in the Firebase error details here?

Comment: if this just started then it may be related to https://api.twitterstat.us/incidents/y9xx059cv0fv

Comment: Personally the problem is no longer present on my applications!